# Multiple Regression approach and ANCOVA approach to check for homogeneity of regression slopes

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, spss, heteroscedasticity, ancova

Hi I have a mixed design set of data with one continuous variable of satisfaction with 2 levels (pre- & post-) and one categorical variable of Service with 3 levels (S1, S2, S3). When running ANCOVA in SPSS, I put pre-satisfaction as covariate and post-satisfaction as DV; the categorical one ofc goes to the fixed factor box. Now when I get the output for Service*pre to check for homogeneity of regression slopes, it was non-significant.

However, when I use the regression approach (creating 2 dummy codes for S1 and S2; then getting 2 product terms dummy1*pre and dummy2*pre; hierarchical regression with dummy1 and dummy2 in first step, the two product terms in 2nd step), the 2nd step showed significant t-value for the product terms, which was not what I was expecting.

Where did I go wrong?